# Customize x-axis tick labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2, I set breaks for a histogram, and the tick labels automatically shows all the breaks, is there a way to customize the showing tick labels?

```
ggplot(plotdata,aes(x=vals))+
geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),fill='cyan')+
geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mycrit,color='red'))+
scale_x_continuous(name='',breaks=mybreaks)+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))
```

[image]
I don't want that many tick labels, only a fraction of them, is there a way to do that?

I also tried setting binwidth instead of breaks and set labels, but I got the error message`Breaks and Labels are different lengths`

Comment: Is your x-axis supposed to be continuous or is it supposed to be categorical? I think you just need to convert it to `numeric`, that is `plotdata$vals = as.numeric(as.character(plotdata$vals))`. Suggested duplicate: [R-FAQ on How to convert from factor to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/903061)

Comment: the vals variable was already a `numeric` variable. I figured out my problem the other way. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
plotdata$vals <- as.numeric(plotdata$vals)
```

Then run your code.

Comment: This wouldn't work as expected if `vals` is a factor.

Comment: You're right, which is the more likely case here. `plotdata$vals <- as.numeric(as.character(plotdata$vals))`